# Align a fluid image element to top of box

Tags: html, overflow

How do I align a fluid image to the top along with the block on the right and make it stretch to the 100% of the box?

[Fluid image not stretching to be flush with borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyU66.png)

```html
<div class="summary">
   <div class="no-overflow">
        <div class="img-responsive"><img src="https://deityworshiponline.com/pluginfile.php/4574/course/section/937/Week1%201250x175.jpg" alt="banner" width="1250" height="175" role="presentation" class="img-fluid ">
        </div>
<h4 style="padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px; font-size: 1.2rem; "><span>
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        &nbsp; &nbsp;WEEK CONTENT: 17 videos &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;47:18, 14 readings, 11 quizzes, 6 exercises, 1 journal entry</span></h4>
   </div>
</div>
```